# Azure tableclient in console app using interactive authentication

Tags: f#, azure-table-storage, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I'm trying to access Azure Table Storage using the [TableClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient?view=azure-dotnet) class, but I want to authenticate using AzureAD credentials via the browser popup.

I have tried 2 approaches and are sure I have things configured correctly in Azure, but I just keep getting

> This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this
> permission.

Here is test code 1 using [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet)

```
let app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("---registered app ID---")
             .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "---tennant id----" )
             .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
             .Build()
let! ar = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(["https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation"]).ExecuteAsync()
let tokenCredential = { new TokenCredential() with
              member x.GetTokenAsync(_,_) = task {return AccessToken(ar.AccessToken, ar.ExpiresOn)} |> ValueTask<AccessToken>
              member x.GetToken(_,_) = AccessToken(ar.AccessToken, ar.ExpiresOn)}
let tc = new TableClient(Uri("https://--endpoint---.table.core.windows.net/"), "--Table--",  tokenCredential)
```

and test 2 using [Azure.Identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.Identity_1.6.0-beta.1/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity)

```
let io = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions(ClientId = "---registered app ID---", RedirectUri = Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"))
let tc = new TableClient(Uri("https://--endpoint---.table.core.windows.net/"), "--Table--", new InteractiveBrowserCredential(io))
```

I have the app registered in Azure & I have added api permissions for Azure Storage, with Admin consent. My account is a Service Administrator for the tennant so I have full access to the storage account. I have scoured all the docs but just cant see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access table data using your Azure AD credentials, your user account should be assigned either [`Storage Table Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-table-data-contributor) or [`Storage Table Data Reader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-table-data-reader) role.

Please assign one of these roles to your user account and re-acquire the token. You should not get the error you are getting then.

Comment: Yep that was it. I'd made the assumption that if I was ServiceAdmin that I had R/W access by default. Obviously not.