# mltable client insists on using interactive authentication

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-python-sdk

I can't get the `mltable` client to stop using interactive authentication to load or save data. The folowing code:

```
registered_data_asset = ml_client.data.get(
    'Dataset',
    label='latest')
            
tbl = mltable.load(f'azureml:/{registered_data_asset.id}')
```

Results in the prompt:

```
Performing interactive authentication. Please follow the instructions on the terminal.
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXXXX to authenticate.
```

I can't use interactive authentication for my use case, I need authentication through environment variables. And this *should* work because `mlclient` is able to use environment authentication.

I have `AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` in my environment vars. I also looked at [Azure tableclient in console app using interactive authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587202/azure-tableclient-in-console-app-using-interactive-authentication) and I've made sure that my app registration has the role Storage Table Data Contributor from the store account that I use for mltables.

It seems that the issue arises when a method from the `Copier` class from `azureml.dataprep.rslex` is called. But this class is a built-in so I can't really determine what is going on.

Does anyone know how to get `mltable` to stop using interactive authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to have been a bug which was fixed in `mltable == 1.6.1` https://pypi.org/project/mltable/1.6.1/

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to get `mltable` to stop using interactive authentication?

You can use the below code to get the **`mltable`** with **`clientsecretcredential`**  authentication using Python SDK.

**Code:**

```
import mltable
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

subscription_id="xxxx"
resource_group="xxxx"
workspace="xxxx"
VERSION="xxxx"
credential=ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id="xxxx",client_id="xxx",client_secret="xxxx")
ml_client = MLClient(credential, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace)
data_asset = ml_client.data.get(name="data098", version=VERSION)
tbl = mltable.load(f"azureml:/{data_asset.id}")
df=tbl.to_pandas_dataframe()
df.head(8)
```

The `ClientSecretCredential` object is used to authenticate the application with appropriate values for the tenant ID, client ID, and client secret.

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-python)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing but I'm still being directed to interactive authentication. Could it be something with roles and permissions in Azure?

Comment: Add a `contributor` role to your application.

Comment: My app registration aleady has the contributor role from the storage account that Azure ML Studio uses. Does it need contributor roles to anything else?

Comment: Try assigning `Storage blob data contributor role` to your application

Comment: For the storage account? I have done this now. Still not able to avoid interactive authentication...